# Google.com NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID Connection Not Private

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, hsts

So i cannot access the domain `google.com` and all of its sub, it's been going on for 2 days, i have no idea what shouldve been done, i have tried :

1. clear ssl certificate cache
2. clear browser data
3. use incognito
4. change too google dns and automatic dns in network and sharing center
5. reinstalling chrome (although this problem occurs on all browsers)

[image: your connection isn't private]

[image: details]

none of the above helped, it's incredibly inconvinient to not be able to access google, is there another way i could fix this? other domains work just fine, even when i tried `google.co.jp` it still runs normally, it's just `.com` ones that i can't access.

edit : screenshot of error details

Comment: You're going to have to post a lot more details to get an answer - what you've provided is little more than "I can't reach google.com."  Can you post the details of the certificate that you get when you try to connect to `google.com`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle i'm not quite sure which details you're asking for, i've updated the post adding the certificate detail thing i got when i clicked on the error

Comment: Same here. I really don't know when exactly this came in, but I saw that was after installing a raw windows 10 (did the same thing other times beefore).